# MAMP, VMware Fusion & DynDNS: Access via internet

Tags: macos, vmware, mamp

i've got a MacMini Server with MAMP Pro with several Virtual Hosts which are accessible via DynDns over internet.
e.g.

```
~/Sites/site1 -> site1.dyndns.org
~/Sites/site2 -> site2.dyndns.org
```

Now I recently installed VMware Fusion and would like to be able to access the VM outside my local network.

I can choose between "bridged" and "NAT". 
Bridged means that the Virtual Machine acts like a real device and it will get its own IP address.
NAT means that the VM will get a subnet IP Address that seams to be only accessible on the host.

I spent hours to read the theory behind all this, but without success.
What I try to realize is something like

```
~/Sites/site1     -> site1.dyndns.org
~/Sites/site2     -> site2.dyndns.org
(VIRTUAL MACHINE) -> vm.dyndns.org
```

The MacMini is behind a Router, the problem with the "bridged"-setting on the VM is that I can only forward a port to one IP address, which is the Address of my MacMini.

So I tried to use the "NAT" setting but I don't know how I can tell my MacMini to forward a request to "vm.dyndns.org" to the virtual machine. At the moment MAMP's apache "catches" all requests.

I tried to change the /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1     site1.dyndns.org
192.168.38.2  vm.dyndns.org
```

this works, but only on the host, not if I enter the address on another computer. you guess, my knowledge is very limited - i'd be happy if someone could just push me into the right direction, there are so many possible config files (/etc/hosts, apache's vhosts.conf, my router's configuration, ...) and i have no idea about the "signal flow"

Comment: Voting to move this to serverfault. While there will be people present here who know enough about this to answer, you can be pretty sure there will be more of them at our sister site.

Comment: @Lieven OK, thanks - i didn't know about server fault. How can the question be moved? Don't want to double post it...

Comment: You can either copy this to serverfault and delete it here, wait until enough users agree moving it and it will be moved automatically or wait until someone does answer it here. I think you would be fastest served by posting it on SF. You can even keep it open here in case someone does answer. If you notice the community agreeing, you can still delete the question before the close count reaches 5 votes.

Comment: Instead of editing your post with an answer, you can answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer. Well done.

Comment: I tried to answer my own question but because I don't have enough posts or something, I wasn't allowed to answer my own question

Comment: Your answer should be posted as an answer, and not as an addendum to the question.

Answer (score 0):

(Solution from the OP):

So i finally got it to work and want to share my solution:

Add the following lines to MAMP(PRO) apache config ("native osx" / "guest os"):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /htdocs/path/in/the/virtual/machine
ServerName vm.dyndns.org 
ProxyRequests On
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.62/ (-> IP Address of the Virtual Machine)
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.62/ (-> IP Address of the Virtual Machine)
</VirtualHost>
```

I guess this will work with any apache which should "forward" requests to another IP.